# Insertar información de un data frame en un mapa en R

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning

Mi intención es mostrar en un mapa de la ciudad de Buenos Aires cuantos Kioskos hay por barrio. Los barrios que tengan más kioskos me gustaría que estén en color más fuerte.
Algo de mi código es

```
df <- data.frame(kioskos)
df$cantidad_k <- as.numeric(cantidad_k)

tabla <- df %>%
        group_by(barrio) %>%
        summarise(cantidad_barrio = sum(cantidad_k))

mymap <- st_read("barrios.json")

ggplot(data = mymap) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=area)) +
  xlab("Longitud") + ylab("Latitud") +
  ggtitle("Cantidad de Kioskos por barrio")
```

El mapa resultante es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el json lo descargue de https://data.buenosaires.gob.ar/dataset/barrios cuyos nombres de barrios no coinciden con los de mi df. Entonces por ejemplo en mi df esta Once y en el json Balvanera. Esto imposibilita la union del df con el df generado por `st.read("barrios.json")` y poder cargar la información al mapa. Si existiese otra forma agradecería que me lo recomienden.

Comment: Lamentablemente no, necesitas algún dato que relacione univocamente los datos del shapefile, muchas veces los datos son desarrollados por organismos distintos que no guardan una misma nomenclatura. Y me pregunto, ¿Tus datos no tienen el número de comuna? si así fuera, por ese lado podrías relarionarlos.

Comment: No tienen ninguno de los df número de columnas. Intenté utilizar un  ```df<- merge(x=tabla,y=mymap,by="barrio",all.y = TRUE) ``` y de todas formas cuando uso la función geom_sf con df y cantidad_kioskos me sale un error de geometry

Comment: Cuando uno intenta crear un mapa y colocar la información propia que no viene con el mapa, existe alguna función para ello ?

Comment: El `merge` es una de esas formas, con `dplyr`  tienes los `join`, pero siempre necesitas una dato que te permita relacionar cada "polígono" del gráfico con los datos que deseas agregar. Es un trabajo, por que son 48 barrios, lo único que se me ocurre es que "matches" manualmente cada barrio en una tabla de equivalencias y recién ahí hagas la relación.

Comment: Algo así me paso con un mapa que hice relacionándolo con datos del indec, en un lado tenía `Neuquen` y en otro `Neuquén` con acento, finalmente terminé editando manualmente los datos para poder hacer la relación.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta @PatricioMoracho. Ya lo resolví, arreglé mi     
df con ```replace``` y ```grep``` y pude hacer el match correctamente